# Call WCF hosted in SharePoint from JQuery

Tags: visual-web-part, wcf

I created a WCF Service hosted in JQuery, when I navigate to the web service in browser and pass a parameter to it, I get back the data correctly, for example like this:

`htp://server:6666/sites/test/_layouts/15/mycustomservice.svc/getitembyid(1)`

I get back the item correctly, but when I do that in a webpart, I keep getting errors, he is the ascx for the webpart:

```
<input id="txtID" type="text" name="txtID" />
<input id="btnID" type="button" value="Get Item Name By ID" onclick="GetMyItem()" />
<script type='text/javascript'>
var txtValue = document.getElementById("txtID").value;

function GetMyItem() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
      url: 'htp://server:6666/sites/test/_layouts/15/mycustomservice.svc/getitembyid',
        data: '{"ID":"1"}',
        success: function (itemtitle) {
            alert(itemtitle);

        },
        error: function () {
            alert('There was an error');
            return;
        }

    });
}
</script>
```

I keep getting: There was an error, any solution?

Comment: update: I keep getting [object Object] error.

Comment: I just wrote it like that because I am having trouble writing http here on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the JSON output look like?

Have you tried changing success to look like this?

```
success: function (item) {
            alert(item.title);

        }
```

Without knowing what the object looks like I cannot be sure but I suspect you are doing `alert` on the entire object, which calls `toString` on the object itself causing `[object Object]` to show in the alert box.

**EDIT AFTER COMMENTS:**

Since your service isn't actually serving JSON try this:

```
$.get('htp://server:6666/sites/test/_layouts/15/mycustomservice.svc/getitembyid(1)', function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

But you need to write your service so that it does serialize your objects to JSON. I assume the text is hard coded as just a demo? If so, have it send an object like this:

```
{ title: "my first item"}
```

**Edit based on SP SE chat conversation:**

If the JSON looks like this: `{"ID":"1","ItemTitle":"item 1"}`

try this code:

```
function GetMyItem() {
//Notice I changed POST to GET and your URL
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'htp://server:6666/sites/test/_layouts/15/mycustomservice.svc/getitembyid(1)',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.ItemTitle);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('There was an error');
            return;
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: now I tried with the item.d, which is the data coming back from the JSON, it says undefined.

Comment: Post the JSON output you see when you browse to the URL, please.

Comment: When I browse to the url like that: 

htp://server:6666/sites/test/_layouts/15/mycustomservice.svc/getitembyid(1) , it gives me the output like this:

"My First Item"

But when I use JQuery to get the value, it's not working.

Comment: even calling item.title gives me undefined. how can I troubleshoot it? it doesn't go to the success part, it goes to the error part of the code

Comment: Are you saying that when you visit that URL in a browser you see EXACTLY and LITERALLY: `My first item` and not JSON? Here is an example of what JSON objects look like: `{title: "My first item", description: "A more detailed explanation."}`

Comment: I get prompted to open a .json file, and when I open it I see the: "My first item", without that {}, just "My first item"

Comment: That's not JSON. I am going to suggest your thread be migrated to SE. This is more a general jQuery/JavaScript question.

Comment: but the file extension is .json that's opened in browser? that's weird!

Comment: It's an issue with your web service. It tells the browser it is JSON but it does not format the content correctly.

Comment: so what should I do in this case?

Comment: UPDATE: I implemented a class in my code and could return data as JSON format, but I still can't get data in JQuery, what should I use? POST or GET? What should I write in the url attribute. 

Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9426/discussion-between-robert-kaucher-and-sp-dev)

Comment: Hi Robert, can you answer my question here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71969/read-data-from-list-with-rest-javascript-error-unable-to-get-property-d-of