# read data from list with REST + Javascript : Error : unable to get property d of undefined or null reference

Tags: json

I am trying to get item from SharePoint list by passing a parameter with the ID to the list and retrieving the item. My code is this:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://mysite:5555/_api/web/lists/getbytitle("my list")/items/getbyid(1)',
header: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
success: function(data){ 
Var jsonObject= JSON.parse(data.body);
alert(jsonObject.d.Title);}  });
```

the file returned is an xml file with a long amount of data, I have an error that I could trace stating: unable to get property d of undefined or null reference

Any hint?

Comment: The big V in Var is a typo i guess? Take a look with for example fiddler to se how the response you are getting is actually looking

Comment: I tried that, If I take the url in fiddler and put it in the address bar, I could see the document, but my problem is parsing the document, I have an error when I try to read the item

Comment: I guess one thing to ensure is that that that you have an Item with ID 1 and that the list is called "my list". Otherwise your code looks correct. I would look at the JSON head data in the Chrome developer tools, that should show you what your trying to display.

Comment: Any resolution on this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to parse the data the way you are. A get by ID returns a single object in JSON format.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://mysharepoint.com/_api/lists/getbytitle('Test List')/items/getbyid(3)",
    headers: { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose'},
    success: function(data){ 
       alert(data.d.Title);
}  });
```

That will return a request body that looks like this:

```
{
    "d": {
        "__metadata": {
            "id": "f02d2168-0e8c-40ec-8222-7b97377e550b",
            "uri": "https://sharepoint.domain.com/_api/Web/Lists(guid'efd16a43-aaf4-44fd-a9a1-4634afe328ac')/Items(3)",
            "etag": "\"1\"",
            "type": "SP.Data.Test_x0020_ListListItem"
        },
        "Title": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore ",
        "Test_x0020_Item": "Enter Choice #1",
        "DueDate": null,
        "DateCompleted": null,
        "StatusId": 3,
        "OtherInfo": null,
        "ID": 3,
        "Modified": "2014-02-28T02:11:22Z",
        "Created": "2014-02-28T02:11:22Z",
        "AuthorId": 12,
        "EditorId": 12,
        "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
        "Attachments": false,
        "GUID": "4769a6db-3a22-4c53-922f-0d6744f82fb0"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try appending Title in the url like this:

```
url: 'http://mysite:5555/_api/web/lists/getbytitle("my list")/items/getbyid(1)?$select=Title'
```

Comment: Thanks Nadeem, 

Same issue, I opened the request in Fiddler, and copied the GET requested, pasted it in URL in Firefox, and could get the file, but through JavaScript I am not able to retrieve it properly

Comment: Are you sure about the name of the field. For example I have seen in the past in SharePoint 2010 that REST uses display name of the field minus any spaces and the field names are also case sensitive. See this http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2012/01/sharepoint-2010-rest-api.html

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the column field that comes by default from SharePoint. Isn't that the case?

Comment: Just thought you may have changed the name of the field.

Comment: ah, no, what should I do in that case?

Comment: I can't see what is wrong with above JQuery. Also, I can't test it  as I don't have either of SP 2010 and SP 2013 VMs available right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://mysite:5555/_api/web/lists/getbytitle("my list")/items/getbyid(1)/?$select=Title',
header: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
success: function(data){ 
alert(data.d.results.Title);}  });
```

It is hard to help you without knowing what your results look like.  What does the JSON data look like expanded in your debugging window?